# Creating a installation package for an Indesign JavaScript

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

Not sure if the heading is clear enough for what I am looking to do. But  here's the explanation:

I have a .jsx file, which does something. I want to create a setup file for mac and pc, just like we have `.jar, .exe, .dmg`. When the user installs this package, my script `abc.jsx` should automatically be placed inside the `Adobe InDesign CS5/Scripts/Scripts Panel` folder, but the user should never be able to view the code of `abc.jsx` (obviously because if they do, then my script is no longer my own work, but available for everyones use).

I've seen that you can create setup files for your Java programs, but is there a way to do it for `.jsx` files, which are primarily  `Adobe ID Scripts`? I'm more of a web guy, with some ID skills, so I don't know how to go about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To protect your source code - compile it as a .jsxbin file.  Once you have a .jsxbin a simple bat file (or whatever the equiv is on a mac) can simply copy/paste the .jsxbin to the correct location.

Comment: I'm trying this. But, I would like something similar to those `setup` files we have, where the user can just click on it and that installs the script in the destination.

Comment: you can just double click on a batch file and it will run.  On windows at least.  I am sure there is a mac variation of the idea though I don't know the details.  Just use the doco here to construct an appropriate command: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true.  Type the command into a text file with the .bat extension and double click the file.  You .jsxbin file will be copied.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an installable setup, you need to use a [setup compiler like Inno](https://www.kymoto.org/products/inno-script-studio), which is free and awesome.

I recommend you have the setup install your script to the user's InDesign roaming directory, such as:
`C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\InDesign\Version 7.0\en_US\Scripts\Scripts Panel`

To obfuscate the code, do as Anna Forrest suggests and compile it to .jsxbin.